# AJAX upload file

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know there is a ton of questions like this but I can't get things to work :(
In script below only "test=bla" is posted and file is not. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!!!

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" onchange="fileUploadChange(this);"   />


function fileUploadChange(e) {
    var mydata = new FormData();
    mydata.append("test", "bla");
    mydata.append("fff", e.files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TestApp/Home/fileUpload",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: mydata,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
        error: function (error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

After further investigation I have figured it out: in .NET MVC, Controller.Request object has Form property and Files property. Simple data items like strings, integers etc can be found in the Form.Keys, Files are located in Request.Files

Comment: @Çağrı Backend get test=bla but doesn't get fff at all

Answer (score 1):

u missed , between success and error methods.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TestApp/Home/fileUpload",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: mydata,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You r right but it's just a typo in the question. Not the real problem. Thank you tho!

Comment: this ajax code is right. it works then problem is in your backend. so u should share also backend code too

Comment: backend is --  Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form.AllKeys);
OR: Request.Form.Count
And I'm getting only one key.

Comment: I mean are u using .net core or .net mvc ? can u share your code that take request from ajax?

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes I was looking in a wrong place :( Thank you. Your question helped me think in a right direction.